Linear span of an algebraic variety
I have an ideal $I = (f_1,\ldots,f_M) \in \Bbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_N]$ generated by (lots of) quadratic and linear polynomials, some of them inhomogeneous, but none of the generators contain constant terms. I used a CAS to construct a Groebner basis $B$ for $I$ and noticed that only a few polynomials of $B$ have high degree, while most are linear. I became interested in the $\Bbb C$-linear span $L = \langle V(I) \rangle$ of the variety cut out by $I$. Is there an algorithm that could be used to get a linear basis for the vanishing ideal of $L$? It does not seem to be true in general that $L$ is the zero set of the linear polynomials that appear in $B$, or is it? (Edit: it's obviously not for say $I = (x_1^2)$, but what if $I$ is indeed radical?)
This might very well be a duplicate, but I found nothing.
Edit 2 (thanks to @HuguesBellemare). Also, is there an algorithm for computing $M =$ the minimal linear subvariety (not necessarily passing through $0$) that contains $V(I)$?

Is the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span really what you're looking for? For example, with $I = (y-1) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, are you more interested in $\langle V(I) \rangle = \mathbb{C}^2$ or in $V(I)$ itself, being the smallest linear variety containing $V(I)$?

@HuguesBellemare I was thinking more about the former variant. AFAIK my variety has a large (enough) automorphism group, I wanted to break as little symmetry as possible, and $V(I)$ contains $0$ since there are no constant terms. Though I won't lose anything if I compute the latter variant :-) , added it to the question.

Since both problems concern the variety rather than the ideal, we will assume that $I$ is radical. We will further assume that $V(I)$ is non-empty, as the problems are uninteresting otherwise.
First, let's consider the algorithm you mentioned with respect to the problem of finding the ideal of the minimal linear variety containing $V(I)$. For clarity, let me state the algorithm:

Let $I$ be a radical ideal. Fix a monomial ordering and compute the reduced Gröbner basis $B$ of $I$ with respect to that monomial ordering. Let $J$ be the ideal generated by the linear polynomials in $B$. Return $V(J)$, the linear variety cut out by $J$.

It turns out that whether or not $V(J)$ is the minimal linear variety containing $V(I)$ depends on the monomial ordering used to compute $B$.
For example, consider $I = (x_1+x_3x_4,x_2+x_3x_4)$, which is radical. Then $B = \{x_1+x_3x_4,x_2+x_3x_4\}$ is the reduced Gröbner basis of $I$ with respect to the lexicographic order (with $x_1 > x_2 > x_3 > x_4$). It follows that $J$ is the zero ideal, hence $V(J) = \mathbb{C}^4$. But we can see that $x_1-x_2 \in I$, which implies that $V(I) \subseteq V(x_1-x_2) \subsetneq V(J)$. Therefore, we conclude that the algorithm fails in this case, but the situation is not hopeless. Indeed, if we change the monomial ordering to the graded lexicographic order, we find the Gröbner basis $B = \{x_3x_4+x_2,x_1-x_2\}$, which leads to $J = (x_1-x_2)$ and $V(J) = V(x_1-x_2)$. The latter turns out to be the minimal linear variety containing $V(I)$.
In fact, the algorithm always works when we use the graded lexicographic order to compute $B$. Indeed, it should be clear from the algorithm that $V(J)$ is a linear variety containing $V(I)$. It remains to prove that $V(J)$ is the smallest such variety, which can be achieved by proving that every linear polynomial $f$ vanishing on $V(I)$ is an element of $J$. By the Nullstellensatz, the ideal of polynomials vanishing on $V(I)$ is the radical of $I$, which is $I$ itself. Therefore, $f \in I$, so there must be a polynomial $g$ in $B$ whose leading monomial is $x_i$ as well. Because we're working with the graded lexicographic order, all the other monomials in $g$ consist of single variables or constants, so subtracting an appropriate multiple of $g$ from $f$ yields another linear polynomial in $I$ with smaller leading monomial. Repeating this process over and over again, we find that $f$ is a combination of linear polynomials in $B$, hence an element of $J$.
More generally, the algorithm always works for monomial orderings whose smallest monomials (after $1$) are the single variables. Conversely, whenever there is a higher degree monomial that is smaller than one of the single variables, it seems that we can cook up examples similar to the one above where the algorithm fails to give the minimal linear variety containing $V(I)$.
Now that we have an algorithm to find the minimal linear variety $V(J)$ containing $V(I)$, finding $L = \langle V(I) \rangle$ is a matter of linear algebra. If the equations defining $J$ are homogeneous, or equivalently if $V(J)$ passes through the origin, there is nothing to do. On the other hand, if the equations defining $J$ are inhomogeneous, we can solve the system of linear equations to get a basis for the homogeneous system plus a particular solution. Adding the particular solution to the basis extends the latter to a basis of $L$. Should we want to find defining equations for $L$, we can always do so, again using linear algebra (in the dual space).
Finally, let me mention that we can get a finer "linear picture" of $V(I)$ when the latter is reducible. Indeed, instead of finding the minimal linear variety containing $V(I)$, we can decompose $V(I)$ into irreducible components and consider the union of the minimal linear varieties containing each component.

Very nice, thanks a lot! So, in my case, this also seems to prove $L = M$ (under the assumption that $I=\sqrt I$), since there are no constant terms, and degrees can't lower while computing a Groebner basis; am I right?

Yes, in your case it is true that $L = M$ since there are no constant terms. However, you need to use a "good" monomial ordering (e.g. the graded lexicographic order) to compute the Gröbner basis if you want the algorithm to give you $M$.
